# Source Not Available for System.Web.Http.dll even though symbols loaded

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have followed the various instructions, such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx. I can see the call details in the stack trace:

[image: Stack Trace]

but when I click on a System.Web.Http.dll or System.Net.Http.dll line, I see

[image: Source not available]

I have checked in the Modules that the symbols have been loaded:

[image: Symbols loaded]

Also checked that there are no source files being skipped:

[image: Not skipped]

If I click on mscorlib line, I am prompted for a source file, so that DLL works fine.

Visual Studio version: 2015.
System.Web.Http version: 5.2.3.0

From what I can tell, this can happen when there is a version that is not yet available, so it falls back to pdb without symbols (not sure why it would still indicate that symbols were loaded in module view).

If it is not possible to view the source if would be good to know how to see what is going wrong with the symbol loading so that it is possible to identify this case in the future.